# Exclude parameter from RequestBody - Swagger

Tags: spring-boot, rest, controller, swagger

I have two methods in one controller with the same obejct as arguments:

```
@PostMapping("/pg-import")
public String importProcessGroup(@RequestBody NiFiArguments niFiArguments) {
    log.info("Called method importFlow");

@PostMapping("/pg-change-version")
public String changeVersionProcessGroup(@RequestBody NiFiArguments niFiArguments) {
    log.info("Called method importFlow");
```

Pojo object:

```
@Data
public class NiFiArguments {

    private String bucketIdentifier;
    private String flowIdentifier;
    private String flowVersion;
    private String baseUrl;
    private String processGroupId;
}
```

I would like to exclude processGroupId attribute from importProcessGroup method. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean, the object received by the `/pg-import` does not contain `processGroupId` field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that would be to Subclass NiFiArguments into a separate class.

```
@Data
public class NiFiArguments {

    private String bucketIdentifier;
    private String flowIdentifier;
    private String flowVersion;
    private String baseUrl;
}

@Data
public class NiFiArgumentsWithProcessGroup extends NiFiArguments {

    private String processGroupId;
}
```

Then use the different objects in your two methods.